# El tag [poo] es sinónimo de [orientación-a-objetos]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Eso.

Existen [poo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poo) y [orientación-a-objetos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orientaci%c3%b3n-a-objetos), y se refieren a lo mismo. Habría que unificarlos antes de que crezcan.

Y que podamos soportar tags con tildes ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hecho. Se ha creado el sinónimo:

> [orientación-a-objetos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orientaci%c3%b3n-a-objetos) (etiqueta maestra) - [poo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poo)

El término **orientación a objetos** es más descriptivo, mientras que **poo** es esto  en inglés.

---

Debido al comentario de @dwarandae, y reforzado por el de @toledano, he intercambiado los sinónimos.

> [poo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poo) (etiqueta maestra) - [orientación-a-objetos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orientaci%c3%b3n-a-objetos)

Comment: `poo` está en español: **P**rogramación **O**rientada a **O**bjetos. En inglés es Object Oriented Progamming: `oop`.

Comment: @toledano Sí, pero alguien lo puede entender como el emoji. Además, como ya dije, es más descriptiva la etiqueta.

Comment: Dudo muchísimo que alguien use 'orientación a objetos', así sea más descriptivo que poo. En la literatura poco, por no decir nada, se usa ese término.

Comment: @dwarandae Cambiado

Comment: @toledano Ahora me doy cuenta que tenías razón. Ya lo cambié.

Comment: Ya entendí lo de `poo`... iba a proponer Programación Orientada Para Objetos, mucho mejor, ¿no? =)

Comment: @toledano Sí, el problema es que, como ya dijeron en la otra respuesta, tiene 32 caracteres, y el máximo permitido es 25. Creo que [tag:poo] está bien.

Answer (score 3):

Yo creé la etiqueta [poo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poo). Inicialmente quise crearla como `programación-orientada-a-objetos` que es el [**término correcto**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos) pero lamentablemente el sistema solo permite hasta 25 caracteres en los tags como máximo, por lo cual opté por dejarla como [poo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poo).

Pienso que por el sinónimo debe ser en este sentido

[poo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poo) <-- `orientación-a-objetos`

Comment: A pesar de que este es un sitio en español, tener una etiqueta que signifique "caca" en inglés resulta un tanto chocante.

Comment: Estaba esperando que aliguen diga algo parecido. Pero al final este sitio es en español y no me parece por que el hecho que un término pueda tener otro significado en inglés u otro idioma sea motivo suficiente para evitarlo.

Comment: Sólo lo decía como comentario, no me opondría por algo así. A mí personalmente no me gusta usar siglas dentro de lo evitable, sobre todo para términos genéricos, por lo que preferiría `orientación-a-objetos`.